# In which DLL library does "internet explorer_server" class/component reside?

Tags: winapi

There is a class/component or whatever in WIN32API ambiguous to me called `internet explorer_server` which displays an internet page, URL, or HTML content I found it in a program but I don't know it and I can't reach it.

[image]

Something like that:

[image]

I want to know:

- In which DLL library does it reside?
- What is its real name in its DLL library?

Comment: [MSHTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/hh801968(v=vs.85))

Comment: Note: don't use MSHTML, use [`WebView2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/win32) instead. MSHTML is ancient and not very well maintained.

Comment: You are looking at the window **class** name. Any process can register a window class of that name. Now the question is: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable: because I have seen a program use it, so  I just wanted to know which library "internet explorer_server" belongs to for some reason. that's it